# How do I connect multiple water-filled syringes?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, fluid-mechanics, pneumatic

I'm trying to connect 4 separate syringes containing water and we need water-tight tubing to prevent water from leaking out of the system. The water would theoretically need to be pushed out of one syringe and into another syringe. We were wondering if there was anything relatively cheap that could do the job? I've included an image as reference.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If the pressure is not too high you can use something like the Luer system there are plenty of options for connectors and valves etc.. I have found parts up to 1050 PSI. But most stuff can't handle more than 50 PSI.

You can get them from all kinds of medical supply sites and even sites like ebay and amazon. I have found [this site](https://www.qosina.com/) after a quick search for Luers and they seem to have all kinds of [switches](https://www.qosina.com/onoff-switch-valve) and [connectors](https://www.qosina.com/connectors) for Luer syringes. With this system you would connect all your tubing and valves (maybe even with a glue) and then screw the syringes on. This makes filling the system and swiching parts pretty easy. These parts are also all made from plastic so they are really cheap. I have found them to be pretty leak proof as long as you don't use something oil or too high pressure (remember it's all plastic). If you want you can always put glue on the connectors to seal them even better.

If you need to switch the flow between the syringes use something like [this 3-way Stopcock I found on amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07QWM8FFJ) or [this high pressure (1050 PSI) one i found on qosina.com](https://www.qosina.com/3-way-stopcock-2-female-luer-locks-swivel-male-luer-lock-99740).

If you need something more durable you might not want to use syringes at all.

I don't know what exactly you want to accomplish with your setup but if you are looking for the syringes to level off or something similar you might not get good results because of the high friction of syringes. So keep in mind that movement of the syringes will probably be pretty jumpy and not at all smooth.

Another option would be to use a proper hydraulic system, but that would be significantly more expensive (at least 20x). So if cost is your main consideration and the limits of syringes are fine you should look for Luer.

Comment: one manufacturer of luer fitments is VALUE PLASTICS, they have a very extensive line of syringe connectors of all types. Not expensive, but you have to buy in bulk.

Comment: I would probably just go to a local pharmacy and ask what they can sell me. Maybe even ask at a doctors office. If they are to expensive I would look on ebay. Those big suppliers are usually only worth it for huge quantities. The described setup looks like about 10 parts total.

Comment: @totalynotanoob So I'm trying to block the lasers and put individual masses on top of each syringe. A correct combination would cause the masses to be at the right level to block the lasers which are at different heights. Do you think there's a better way of doing this?

Comment: @John If that means you need smooth movement caused only by the syringes then i don't think syringes would work well. They probably won't move until there is a lot of weight on them and then they will jump an stop again (probably having moved farther than you would like). You might be able to find some hydraulics with less friction but not without a pretty high price tag  (at least compared to syringes)....

Comment: ...But since this all really depends on the weights and type of syringe you are using I would just try it. Maybe fill one syringe and then put a weight on there. If it empties out smoothly you should be good to go, if it gets stuck or moves jumpy then you might want to try something different. I don't know your exact aim but maybe a setup relying on water displacement instead of pressure could also work. That would also be cheap and easy to setup with a bit of Styrofoam.

Answer (score 0):

One can use aquarium tubing fittings to match the tubing diameter you are using. These fittings can be found in tropical fish retail locations, as well as online.

Another source of similar fittings is the local hardware store. Our area is populated with Ace Hardware stores and I've purchased more than a few plastic barbed tubing fittings. In your application, you would be seeking tee fittings.

Some sprinkler systems use similarly barbed fittings and can be found at the big box stores and/or sprinkler companies. These are less likely to be the correct choice, as the diameter usually is 1/4" or greater.

One source for a smaller fitting (1/16") is [MSC Direct](https://www.mscdirect.com/product/details/36672657). Image below courtesy MSC Direct.

[image: plastic barbed tee fitting]